# How to modulate with ASK (Amplitude-shift keying) a signal

Tags: java, signal-processing

I am writing to know if is possible to modulate with ASK a signal using java. Does anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Signal generation requires a hardware device. What hardware are you talking about?

Comment: I'm assuming audio, but the question is very vague.

Comment: i have to send ultrasound from smartphone ( like iPhone and others.. ). this ultrasound must be modulated cause i have to associate a smartphone and a device, but there are many device associated with other smartphone

Comment: You can't send true ultrasound from consumer devices such as smartphones - the audio hardware simply does not support it. You might be able to generate annoying stuff at around 16 - 18 kHz but this will be audible to young people and to many animals, and this is not really ultrasound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to amplitude modulate a carrier signal within the audible spectrum then you can just change the amplitude of a synthesised sine wave on-the-fly.

So the carrier signal would be:

```
y = A * sin (2 * pi * f0 / Fs * n)
```

where `A` = amplitude, `f0` is the carrier frequency (Hz), e.g. 10 kHz, `Fs` is the sample rate (Hz), e.g. 44.1 kHz, and n is the sample number.

You would change A according to your modulation scheme, e.g. at the start of every symbol period (e.g. every 10 ms, for a symbol rate of 100 baud) set A to the required value.